# Доработать скрипт на проверку option

Tags: jquery, rxjava

Помогите, пожалуйста, доработать скрипт.
Есть список категорий, и есть информация, которая скрыта, при выборе определенной категории, скрытый блок показывается. Якобы все хорошо, но есть маленькое "НО". Если зайти повторно на страницу редактирования публикации блок снова будет скрыт, хотя категория которую мы выбрали выбрана. Чтобы блок снова появился нужно повторно перевыбрать определенную категорию.

При сохранении публикации выбранному option присваивается selected="", что и показывает активную категорию.

```
<option value="1" selected="">Рецепты</option>
```

Как сделать, чтобы скрипт проверял, если у Рецепта стоит selected="", значит показать блок?

```js
$(function() {
  var $dependerItem = $('.dependent');
  $('.cat0 #category').change(function() {
    var curentSelectedVal = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    if (curentSelectedVal == 1) {
      $dependerItem.removeClass('hiden');
    } else {
      $dependerItem.addClass('hiden');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hiden {
  display: none;
}

.dependent {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cat0">
  <label class="label-mod" for="category">Категории</label>
  <select data-placeholder="Выберите категорию ..." name="catlist[]" id="category" style="width:350px;">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">Рецепты</option>
    <option value="10">Напитки</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="dependent hiden">
  Я ВИДИМЫЙ
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сам спросил, сам и отвечу...

```
$('.cat0 #category option[selected=""]').each(function() {
$('.dependent').toggleClass('hiden', !this.value);
});
```